# Showing a single Category only on a Wordpress Custom Post Type page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have made a custom post type with custom fields etc for a page on my website...Currently it works fine and shows all of the courses I have created: http://seedcreativehub.co.uk/book-seedcreativehub-courses/

However, I would now only like the page to display one specific course category.

The code I'm using is below, and I thought it would be as simple as adding in **'category_name' => 'upcoming-event'** underneath the post type, however it doesn't seem to showing anything at all...

I can't think what I'm doing wrong, if someone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
        <?php
          $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'courses',
            'category_name' => 'upcoming-event'
          );
          $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="col-xs-3 course">

            <?php
              $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
              $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail-size', true );
            ?>

            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_url[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" graphic></a></p>
            <h3><?php the_field('event_date'); ?></h3>
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>


          </div>


          <?php $portfolio_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>
          <?php if ( $portfolio_count % 4 == 0): ?>

          </div><div class="row">

          <?php endif; ?>


          <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Thanks for looking,

Shaun.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) parameter while querying posts based on taxonomy.

```
    <?php
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'courses',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'course-category',  // Taxonomy name
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'upcoming-event',   // Term name
            ),
        ),
      );
      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
```

Comment: Perfect - Thanks so much! :)